# Not able to download or save anything using save as pdf in google chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

I am not able to use the "Save as PDF" printing option on chrome. Whenever I print something using save as pdf, I get the below message on the screen.
"The selected printer is not available or not installed correctly. Check your printer or try selecting another printer."